# Android - to listen the phone state

Tags: java, android

In my application, I need to set a phoneStateListener so that when the connectivity is off,I am able to cache the required updations in a hashtable.I know how to do that using phoneStateListener in a single activity.But can you suggest how can I do it an efficient way other than repeating the same in all activities?. I am a novice in both Java and android.I thought about doing inheritance,But all my classes are already inheriting another class.So how can I implement this without using inheritance?

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, you want a single hash table that can be used across all activites?

You could wrap the hashtable in a class with public put/remove/etc methods, declare everything static and instantiate the hashtable once in that class. Then all activities would go by that class to use the hashtable.

Comment: the problem is not in making hashtable,I need a phonestateListener throughout my application.

Comment: I assume you could do something similiar with the phoneStateListener.